# How should I create a Java application, where do I place the class?

Tags: java

First of all, I know how to build a Java application. But I have always been puzzled about where to put my classes. There are proponents for organizing the packages in a strictly domain oriented fashion, others separate by tier.

I  have a problems with

naming and placing
So,

Where do you put your domain specific constants?

Where do you place class for stuff which is both infrastructural and domain specific (for instance I have a FileStorageStrategy class, which stores the files either in the database, or alternatively in database)?

thx

Comment: Your question is very broad, perhaps too broad.  You can place your classes anywhere you want; you can place constants anywhere you want.  I would seriously recommend you find a good book on Java object-oriented software engineering-a book that presents more than just syntax.  Books that describe Java APIs is a great way to "kill two birds".   Good luck.

Comment: Maybe it will be better if you provide a small example program demonstrating where doing one thing or the other, becomes a problem

Comment: @RichardJessop have you heard these terms he is using, like "domain specific" and "infrastructure specific" ? what book have you read that mentions that?

Comment: I don't even get anything if I search for difference between domain specific and infrastructure specific.  Let alone the terms you are using. Maybe your terms aren't translating properly or you are using wrong/unclear terms? In which case best to define your terms

Comment: @barlop: Yes, I have heard of these of terms; in fact, I use "domain specific" very frequently as I do research in DSLs.  "Infrastructure specific" is a phrase I don't use; however, I do understand the intent of the question.  For an excellent text on "domain specific ...", I would refer you to Martin Fowler "Domain-Specific Languages".

Comment: @RichardJessop oh I do have an idea what a domain specific language is/ DSL, I've used bits of DSLs in Rails, that has some ruby-based DSLs. Java is so strict though in its syntax that I guess you couldn't have much flexiblity writing a DSL in java.  He should give examples of what he is talking about re his code though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excellent approach to coming up with your own style and approach to class naming and organization style:

1. Find a great IDE.  I really like Eclipse.  It provides all of the features that follow.
2. Identify a naming style and organizational layout.  This is an inductive approach to developing your own effective best practices.
3. Ask yourself: does #2 help you or are you fighting with it?
4. Archive your system frequently.  Use a great configuration management system like git or GitHub!  It will make #5 easier.
5. Make small changes.  The IDE should allow you to rename class at any point of your system and make the changes globally.  Moving classes should be equally easy.  Doing this will prevent getting hamstrung by analysis: analysis paralysis.
6. Loop to #2.  Yes, infinite loop.  I've been doing this loop for a very long time.  (Duh, it's an infinite loop!)  In fact, sometimes I thrash: I flip-flop between 2 styles.
7. While in your infinite loop, examine online style guides and coding standards.  Google and NASA JPL have great ones.  Also, look at the great open-source APIs to see how the community of developers name and organize.  If someone else is going to work with your code, you don't want to confuse them in any way.  Worst case, they'll ignore what you did and rewrite it.

Don't be afraid to experiment.  Don't be afraid to make mistakes.  Don't always rely on what others do or have done.  Good luck.